# Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer does not allow moving of vertical border of SplitContainer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-core, windows-forms-designer

Following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/walkthrough-windows-forms-designer?view=vs-2019), in step 5 it  says,

> Select the vertical border between the panels and drag it to the right, so that most of the space is taken by the left panel.

When I select the vertical border, it appears to highlight it, then when I try to drag it, it moves a little bit, then I can't select it again since it tries to select one of the panels instead. From what I can see, nothing from the properties window looks like it is affecting this.  I have also not changed any settings relating to winforms (I think anyways), so am I clicking the wrong thing? Is there some kind of border that is preventing it from moving?

Split container with the vertical border selected; cursor is invisible:
[image]

Comment: Try to increase the splitter's width to make it easier to grab. - _I have also not changed any settings relating to winforms (I think anyways),_ Hm, better make sure!

Comment: @TaW Although it is easier to grab now, it's still not moving

Comment: Then one or more properties are set wrong. Try to replace it by one out of the box..

Comment: @TaW I don't know what you mean by `replace it by one out of the box`

Comment: I meant drop a new splitcontainer panel to see if that one works

Comment: @TaW No, it doesn't unfortunately, and neither does dropping a splitcontainer into a splitcontainer

Answer (score 0):

The vertical line in SplitContainer doesn't work in a .NET Core project, but works as expected in a .NET Framework project. The linked tutorial follows the Framework template.
This looks more like a bug than an intended change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble, you can set the SplitContainer's SplitterDistance property at design-time to manually set the size of the split panels, and the position of the splitter.

FWIW, I can't reproduce the problem in the latest .NET 5 WinForms (.NET 5.08, VS 2019 16.10.4).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. I had the same problem in the designer, although in runtime the splitter worked fine.

For design time, for me it worked to cut out the left component to the clipboard, move the splitter, and paste the component again.